# Google Play Console - Does publishing overview need to be completed before any releases on any track are available?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded a release to internal testing track. Before uploading a completed all publishing overview noticed. One of them was data safety/collection review. I completed that and released the internal test. Then, I got a notice saying my data safety review was rejected. I fixed it again, but when my testers click on the testing URL, they keep downloading the old version of the app.

Does the change I made to the data safety publishing overview need to be approved first before the new version on the internal track is released for testers?

[image]